# I have an Custom Edittext and im using viewmodel but text input doesnt get updated in viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

My normal edittext which works:

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8_dp"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="@={viewModel.emailId}"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_default_input" />
```

Now Im using:

```
 <myapp.app.widgets.edittext.MyCustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/panEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8_dp"
                    android:hint="PAN number"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.pan}"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_default_input" />
```

Now this doesnt work.

my method

```
!viewModel.isPanValid() -> binding.panEditText.setError(viewModel.panError.value)
```

doesnt work but for email it works what to do?

the
MyCustomEditText is just en extended class

```
public class MyCustomEditText extends LinearLayout implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcher, TextView.OnEditorActionListener, View.OnClickListener {
```

It includes just a UI stuff and on focus listener etc

Comment: we have no idea what `<myapp.app.widgets.edittext.MyCustomEditText` is, so it's impossible to give an answer, please update to include enough information for us to replicate

Comment: @a_local_nobody it only a extend class to "public class MyCustomEditText extends LinearLayout implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcher, TextView.OnEditorActionListener, View.OnClickListener"

Comment: How many times does this happens `!viewModel.isPanValid()`?

Comment: @cutiko my interntion is when i click next button, or say submit button. the email also have function that works.

Comment: `MyCustomEditText` does not have 2 way binding so How is your `viewModel.panError` being Set ?  Also whats this `MyCustomEditText extends LinearLayout`? How can EditText extends by a ViewGroup ? Those all attributes you have set in xml does not work for ViewGroup ..  Can u add the full code of `MyCustomEditText` with question .

Answer (score 0):

`setError` is a function of `EditText`. Your `MyCustomEditText` is not an `EditText` but a `LinearLayout` so you can't call `setError` on it because it simply doesn't exist for that class. I don't know the rest of `MyCustomEditText` but I assume it has an `EditText` inside it and you might have a reference to it, say `editTextInThisClass`. If not you will need to create one. Then you could write this in your `MyCustomEditText`:

```
public void setError(CharSequence error) {
    editTextInThisClass.setError(error)
}
```

but I wonder if you actually intended for it to be a `LinearLayout`. If not you should just change `LinearLayout` to `EditText`

Comment: Ok i will try this, but what the issue is not only about using setError, linear layout was used to create beautiful UI, how I can get updated value here?

Comment: @SãúrâßhJáðhàv it's hard to say what you exactly need without knowing more details, but I wonder if your custom EditText is actually the best way. Couldn't this LinearLayout not just be defined in an xml layout file? Or do you really need some custom implementation?

Comment: there is some custom implementation done by company employees